# Como declarar métodos abstratos na interface em OOP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Gostaria de saber como faço para criar um método na interface de um programa em orientação a objetos, onde esse método receba parâmetros... Exemplo estou criando um objeto controle remoto onde tem a função(método) de aumentar volume, porém para eu aumentar o volume preciso receber um valor vindo do teclado para aumentar o volume, Estou usando o PHP

```
interface Controlador { 

    public function ligar();
    public function desligar();
    public function aumentar_volume();
    public function diminuir_volume();
    public function abrir_menu();
}
```

Página da classe que implementa a interface. COloquei apenas o bloco com o corpo da função, não a página toda.

```
public function aumentar_volume($valor){

       if($this->getLigado(true)){
           if($this->getVolume <= $this->getVolume_max){
               $this->setVolume($this->$getVolume() + $this->getValor);
           }else{
               echo "Volume já atingiu o volume máximo";
           }
       } 
    }
```

> **Fatal error**: Declaration of Controle_remoto::aumentar_volume() must be compatible with Controlador::aumentar_volume() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Programas_Orientacao_Obj\Controle_remoto\Controle_remoto.php on line 4

Comment: Na interface, você definiu o método sem argumentos, mas na classe você definiu um argumento. Esse é o erro. Se o método possui um argumento, ele deve estar presente na interface também.

Comment: Obrigada Anderson mas como faço isso? pode me ajudar por favor, não estou conseguindo colocar este argumento na interface.

Comment: Como tentou fazer?

Comment: Desta Forma:

interface Controlador {
    private $valor;
    public function ligar();
    public function desligar();
    public function aumentar_volume($valor);
    public function diminuir_volume();
    public function abrir_menu();
}

Comment: Argumento do método é completamente diferente de atributo da classe. Argumento seria `$valor` no método `aumentar_volume`.

Comment: Isso na interface? ou coloco na página que foi implementado a interface?

Comment: Ja consegui Obrigada.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você usa uma interface, uma analogia que você pode fazer é que a classe passa a ser uma caixa preta e o mundo exterior apenas vê a interface. Isto é, a interface irá definir como o mundo externo irá ver sua classe.

Na sua interface, o método `aumentar_volume` não possui argumentos; então seria como você possuir uma porta e colocar um aviso: "pode entrar, não tem chave", mas quando alguém tentar abrí-la, está trancada. É isso que sua interface está fazendo: dizendo para o mundo externo que para chamar o método `aumentar_volume` você não precisa passar nenhum valor como parâmetro, porém quando você implementa o mesmo método na classe, você espera um valor. O PHP entende isso como erro.

De duas, uma: ou a implementação da sua classe está errada e o método não deveria possuir argumentos; ou a implementação da interface está errada e o método deveria possuir argumentos.

Considerando a segunda solução, sua interface ficaria:

```
interface Controlador { 

    public function ligar();
    public function desligar();
    public function aumentar_volume($valor);
    public function diminuir_volume($valor);
    public function abrir_menu();
}
```

Já adicionei o argumento no método `diminuir_volume`, pois parece passar pelo mesmo problema.

Comment: Nossa muito boa a explicação obrigada pela ajuda consegui entender de uma forma muito clara e objetiva, agora rodou meu código. Muito obrigada